# The signed distance from a given point to a 2D slice of a given 3D mesh (for example, obj file)

Tags: computational-geometry

Given a 3D mesh file (.obj) with a point, make a slice across the point to intersect this 3D mesh to get a 2D slice. How to get the signed distance of this point to this 2D profile efficiently? Is there a relevant algorithm or graphics library I can refer to? Thanks a lot！
(If the cutting plane and the corresponding 2D slice are not fixed but change very often (1000HZ), how can I improve efficiency? I think it is relatively expensive to build the AABB tree each time. I am very demanding in terms of performance.)

getting the list of intersection segments using CGAL and building AABB tree of segments each time seems not be very efficient. how can I improve efficiency?

Comment: What are you using the "AABB tree of segments" for? Since it takes greater than linear time to build, why not just iterate through all the segments and find the closest one?

Comment: its unclear what is your input ... I would expect you want SDF to some slice of 3D mesh so input should be plane, 3D mesh and position inside the plane to where you want to calculate SDF however your input does not mention any plane and I got the feeling you define the slice by the point which is not enough ... what precision you need? do you have many queries per the same slice or just few or one ? how complex mesh (how many triangles or whatever) ?